# Resource Id in ViewModel?

Tags: android, unit-testing, viewmodel, junit4

My question is a little different from previous resource access questions. I want to use resource id in viewModel but just resource id, ex: `R.string.error_missing_user_name`. Just wonder if is this approach okey for unit tests ? (Can i access resource id constant in unit test, for ci/cd)

```
    private val _errorMessage = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val errorMessage: LiveData<Int> = _errorMessage

    fun displayError(@StringRes message: Int) {
        _errorMessage.value = message
    }
```

In unit test similar to this

```
    @Test
    fun checkErrorMessage() {
        viewModel.displayError(R.string.error_missing_user_name)
        assertEquals(errorMessage.value, R.string.error_missing_user_name)
    }
```

Comment: I added more detail about question.

Comment: I think you should update your mutable live data that will more better for your testing